# Is there a possibilty to run parallel scripts in G1ANT.Studio

Tags: automation, robotics, rpa, g1ant

Greetings fellow software engineers,

As the title of this post states, I was wondering if there's any possibility to run two scripts at once (any kind of multithreading) inside of G1ANT.Studio?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no possibility to run two scripts at once on the same computer for now, but you can own multiple G1ANT licenses that you can use on different machines, so that robots can communicate with each other and work in parallel.

By the way, if you want to increase the productivity, you can use triggers to launch scripts automatically at a given time ([schedule trigger](https://manual.g1ant.com/G1ANT.Addons/G1ANT.Addon.Core/Triggers/ScheduleTrigger.md)), after a change in a watched directory took place, for example when a new file appears ([file trigger](https://manual.g1ant.com/G1ANT.Addons/G1ANT.Addon.Core/Triggers/FileTrigger.md)), or after you have received an email ([mail trigger](https://manual.g1ant.com/G1ANT.Addons/G1ANT.Addon.Core/Triggers/MailTrigger.md)).

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use macro functionality of G1ANT.Language and create there as many threads or tasks as you want. Downside is that you can only execute there C# code.